# Transparent NavigatorIOS doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, navigator, navigator-ios

I would like to display a 100% transparent Navigator bar, but I have something like light pink instead of the background color :

[image]

Here is my code :

```
<NavigatorIOS
ref='nav'
tintColor="white"
style={{flex: 1}}
initialRoute={{
  title: 'Splash',
  navigationBarHidden: true,
  component: SplashScene
}}/>
```

Thanks a lot for your help,

Margot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NavigatorIOS component is not supported by the React Native team, it is just the Apple iOS navigation bar available in react-native and you only have access to the same options available in xcode. You cannot handle full transparency for the bar in xcode when building a native iOS app without react-native. So you cannot do it with react-native either sadly.

You can use the [react-native-bar](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-navbar) library for a more customizable navigation bar. You will be able to do it with react-native-navbar doing so:
`<NavigationBar tintColor="transparent" />`

You can also [see this link](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-navbar/issues/60) if you need more help
The final result will be something like in [this image](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/11604017/13411902/0aac66ea-df40-11e5-992e-97a4ff4e690e.png)

Comment: Thank you, it's exactly what I needed !

Answer (score 0):

Is this because of the background colour of your main view? If this is the case, then adding a marginTop of 64 to your container view should help.

```
import { Modal, Text, TextInput, TouchableHighlight, View, ListView, NavigatorIOS } from 'react-native';
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

export default class NavigatorIOSApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigatorIOS
        initialRoute={{
          component: MyScene,
          title: 'My Initial Scene',
        }}
        style={{flex: 1}}
      />
    );
  }
}

class MyScene extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    navigator: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  }

  _onForward = () => {
    this.props.navigator.push({
      title: 'Scene ' + nextIndex,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{backgroundColor: 'red', flex: 1, marginTop: 64}}>
        <Text>Current Scene: { this.props.title }</Text>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._onForward}>
          <Text>Tap me to load the next scene</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```